# Liberty: jms lookup

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty

I am working on migrating ear application to liberty. 
As part of this all jndi lookups to beans are converted to java namespace.

However we have jndi lookups for jms or services provided by server etc.

Do we have to convert this to any other format for it to work on liberty.?

Are there any known limitations related to jms on liberty?

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Websphere Liberty Application Server follows the *latest* [JMS 2.0 specifications](https://javaee.github.io/jms-spec/#jms-20), so there are no limitations from that perspective - beside if you used any vendor specific functionality of course. That is something for you to verify.

For example JMS Exception handling, which makes room for vendor implementations. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501338/jms-exceptionlistener/30501740#30501740).

Regarding JNDI - cant see any problem, did you got any errors? It should work fine, I ve not seen any problem from what I ve been involved in. See the examples about JMS in Liberty at [IBM knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_msg_embedded.html)